# Fix Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Tags: mysql, temporary, explain, filesort

I have two simple tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cat_urls (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  SIL_Id int(11) NOT NULL,
  SiteId int(11) NOT NULL,
  AsCatId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Href varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  ReferrerHref varchar(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AddedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  GroupId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  INDEX SIL (SIL_Id, AsCatId)
)

CREATE TABLE products (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CatUrlId int(11) NOT NULL,
  Href varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  SiteIdentity varchar(2048) NOT NULL,
  Price decimal(12, 2) NOT NULL,
  IsAvailable bit(1) NOT NULL,
  ClientCode varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  INDEX CatUrl (CatUrlId)
)
```

And I have pretty simple query:

```
SELECT cu.Href, COUNT(p.CatUrlId) FROM cat_urls cu
       JOIN products p ON p.CatUrlId=cu.Id
       WHERE sil_id=4601038
GROUP by cu.Id
```

EXPLAIN says:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref                     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      cu      ref     PRIMARY,SIL     SIL     4       const                   303     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      p       ref     CatUrl          CatUrl  4       blue_collar_logs.cu.Id  6       Using index
```

Please tell me is there any way to fix "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" and improve perfomance of this query?

Comment: How about `explain
select href, sum
from cat_urls c
join
(
SELECT cu.id, sum(sil_id=4601038) as sum
FROM cat_urls cu
JOIN products p ON p.CatUrlId=cu.Id
GROUP by cu.Id
) t on t.id = c.id`

Comment: `id select_type table  type  possible_keys key      key_len  ref      rows  Extra
1 PRIMARY  <derived2> ALL   (null)   (null)     (null)  (null)     178525398 (null)
1 PRIMARY  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY   PRIMARY     4   t.Id     1   (null)
2 DERIVED  cu   index  PRIMARY,SIL  PRIMARY     4   (null)     29754233 (null)
2 DERIVED  p   ref   CatUrl   CatUrl     4   blue_collar_logs.cu.Id 6   Using index`

Comment: this query executes very long time

Answer (score 2):

It looks that, for some reason, `MySQL` chooses to use the index `SIL` on the first table and it uses it both for lookup (`WHERE sil_id = 4601038`) and grouping (`GROUP BY cu.Id`).

You can tell it to use the `PK` of the table

```
SELECT cu.Href, COUNT(p.CatUrlId) FROM cat_urls cu
    USE INDEX FOR JOIN (PRIMARY)
JOIN products p ON p.CatUrlId=cu.Id
WHERE sil_id=4601038
GROUP by cu.Id
```

and it will produce this execution plan:

```
id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra
---+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+------+-------------
1  | SIMPLE      | cu    | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL             | 1    | Using where
1  | SIMPLE      | p     | ref   | CatUrl        | CatUrl  | 4       | cbs-test-1.cu.Id | 1    | Using index
```

**Ignore the values reported in column `rows`**; they are not correct because my tables are empty.

Notice the `Extra` column now contains only `Using where` but also notice that the join `type` column changed from `ref` (very good) to `index` (full index scan, not quite good).

A better solution is to add an index on column `SIL_Id`. I know, `SIL_Id` is a prefix of index `SIL(SIL_Id, AsCatId)` and in theory another index on column `SIL_Id` is completely useless. But it seems it solves the issue on this case.

```
ALTER TABLE cat_urls
  ADD INDEX (SIL_Id)
;
```

Now use it in the query:

```
SELECT cu.Href, COUNT(p.CatUrlId) FROM cat_urls cu
    USE INDEX FOR JOIN (SIL_Id)
JOIN products p ON p.CatUrlId=cu.Id
WHERE sil_id=4601038
GROUP by cu.Id
```

The query execution plan looks much better now:

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra
---+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+------+-------------
1  | SIMPLE      | cu    | ref  | SIL_Id        | SIL_Id | 4       | const            | 1    | Using where
1  | SIMPLE      | p     | ref  | CatUrl        | CatUrl | 4       | cbs-test-1.cu.Id | 1    | Using index
```

The drawback is that we have an extra index that is (theoretically) useless. It occupies storage space and it consumes processor cycles every time a row is added, deleted or have its `SIL_Id` field modified.